# javascript clock project not displaying to page

Tags: javascript

I looked through a few javascript clock projects and sort of made my own, but I can't get the clock to display. Not sure what I'm missing but I can't get the actual clock to display on the page. This is all I need but stack overflow is making me write more because apparently I can't have a post that's mostly code.

```js
<script>
        function updateClock() {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
            var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        
            // Add a 0 if # is under 10 instead of leaving a blank space
            currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
            currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;
            
            // Conversion to 12-hour time instead of 24-hour time
            var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
            currentHours = ( currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
            currentHours = ( currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

            document.getElementById('.clock')[0].innerHTML = 
            currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
            
           

        }
    </script>
```

```css
body{
    background: rgb(238, 216, 216);
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(136, 181, 230);
    font-size: 35px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

#clock {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Clock Project</h1>
    </div>
    
    <span class="clock"></span>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Well, if you write a function, it might be a smart idea to actually call it as well. Functions on their own don't do anything. I haven't tested it, but you'll probably only have to add `updateClock();` underneath your function so it gets called.

Comment: Thanks, I added that and it didn't do anything...yet.

Comment: Check hev1's answer to your question. He even made it runable. It's working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) with a class name.

Either set the `id` of your span to to "clock" (`<span id="clock"></span>`) and get the element like this: `document.getElementById("clock")`

or use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to get the element like this: `document.getElementsByClassName("clock")[0]`

Since your CSS is styling the element with an `id` of clock with the `#clock` cssRule, your intention was probably to set the `id` of the `span` to "clock".

You should use a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to update the clock every 1000 milliseconds (you aren't actually ever calling your `updateClock` function).

```css
body{
    background: rgb(238, 216, 216);
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(136, 181, 230);
    font-size: 35px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

#clock {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Clock Project</h1>
    </div>
    
    <span id="clock"></span>
    <script>
        function updateClock() {
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
            var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
            var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        
            // Add a 0 if # is under 10 instead of leaving a blank space
            currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
            currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;
            
            // Conversion to 12-hour time instead of 24-hour time
            var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
            currentHours = ( currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
            currentHours = ( currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

            document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = 
            currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
        }
        setInterval(function(){updateClock()}, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
```

You may want to use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Browser_compatibility) so you wouldn't have to do as many calculations to get the date.

In this case, `new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US")` should do just what you want.

```css
body{
    background: rgb(238, 216, 216);
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(136, 181, 230);
    font-size: 35px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

#clock {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Clock Project</h1>
    </div>
    
    <span id="clock"></span>
    <script>
       var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
        function updateClock() {
            clock.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US");
        }
        setInterval(function(){
          updateClock()
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```